# Redirect from a controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am permanently moving part of my site, in the old controller I want a redirect:

```
return redirect()->route('index');
```

How can I make this a 301?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument of the method is route parameters, the third one is the status code and the fourth are the headers. So in your case:

`return redirect()->route('index', [], 301);`

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to do this in my routes file if the 'index' route will no longer be used. This is just so i can easily see it but if not TheFallen's answer is best

`Route::get('index', function(){
    abort(301);
})`